# Is there a way to retrieve all WooCommerce product variations for display on a packing slip using Atum Multi inventory?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We have set up a store using Atum Multi inventory and I'm trying to add stock locations to the packing slip. This is what I have so far:

```
add_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_item_meta', 'wpo_wcpdf_show_product_categories', 10, 3 );
function wpo_wcpdf_show_product_categories ( $document_type, $item, $order ) {
if ($document_type == 'packing-slip') {
        $locations = wp_get_object_terms ( $item['product']->get_id(), 'atum_location', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
        $locations_list = ! empty( $locations ) ? implode( ', ', $locations ) : '&ndash;';

            // get a comma separated list of categories (category links stripped)
            if (isset($item['product'])) {
                echo '<div class="product-categories">Locatie(s): '. $locations_list .'</div>';
            }
       }
}
```

This is coming back empty and I think it's because I need to get all variations. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Jolanda

```
add_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_item_meta', 'wpo_wcpdf_show_product_categories', 10, 3 );
function wpo_wcpdf_show_product_categories ( $document_type, $item, $order ) {
if ($document_type == 'packing-slip') {
        $locations = wp_get_object_terms ( $item['product']->get_id(), 'atum_location', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
        $locations_list = ! empty( $locations ) ? implode( ', ', $locations ) : '&ndash;';

            // get a comma separated list of categories (category links stripped)
            if (isset($item['product'])) {
                echo '<div class="product-categories">Locatie(s): '. $locations_list .'</div>';
            }
       }
}
```

Expecting to get locations on packing slip